# try to create a more linear part in a sigmoid curve

Tags: exponential-function

I want to create a function for a curve which is similar to a sigmoid curve but the center part is linear. That curve must pass through 2 points (-1.5,20) and (1.5,80). The range for y value is [0,100]. I have create two functions which are shown in the figure below.

http://i827.photobucket.com/albums/zz197/koifish1987/curve_zpsaju4fxhn.jpg

sigmoid curve: $y = \frac{{100}}{{1 + {e^{ - \frac{{\ln 4}}{{1.5}}x}}}}$

linear line: $y=20x+50$

I want to make the sigmoid curve (black) closer to the linear line (red). How can I change the sigmoid function to achieve that? Or is there any function which yields the similar curve shape and more linear in the center?

Comment: What does this have to do with linear programming?

Comment: @Math1000: I'm sorry. I have deleted the tag linear programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add terms in the exponent to cancel higher derivatives at the origin. They need to be antisymmetric, and they shouldn't mess up the behaviour at infinity. Powers of $\sin x$ satisfy those requirements. To cancel the third derivative:

$$
\frac1{1+\exp\left(-x-\frac1{12}\sin^3x\right)}=\frac12+\frac x4+O\left(x^5\right)\;.
$$

To cancel the fifth derivative:

$$
\frac1{1+\exp\left(-x-\frac1{12}\sin^3x-\frac{13}{240}\sin^5x\right)}=\frac12+\frac x4+O\left(x^7\right)\;.
$$

And so on. [Here's a plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%20%2F%20%281%20%2B%20exp%20%28-x%20-%20%281%2F12%29%20*%20sin%5E3%20x%20-%2013%2F240*sin%5E5%20x%29%29%20for%20x%3D-4..4) of the second version.

This comes at a price – forcing the function into an "unnatural" linearity at the origin while keeping it analytic causes slight oscillations elsewhere. Of course, if you don't care about analyticity, you should just splice a linear function into a sigmoid.

P.S.: I was assuming that you want to keep the asymptotic behaviour roughly unchanged. If you don't care about that, you can do it more simply:

$$
\frac1{1+\exp\left(-x-\frac1{12}x^3\right)}=\frac12+\frac x4+O\left(x^5\right)\;.
$$

[The plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%20%2F%20%281%20%2B%20exp%20%28-x%20-%20%281%2F12%29%20*%20x%5E3%29%29%20for%20x%3D-4..4) looks a lot like what you wanted, but it converges to the limit  more rapidly than a sigmoid.

The next step in that direction would be

$$
\frac1{1+\exp\left(-x-\frac{x^3}{12}-\frac{x^5}{80}\right)}=\frac12+\frac x4+O\left(x^7\right)\;.
$$

And, since you wanted to have an $x^7$ term for rapid convergence, here's the next step, too:

$$
\frac1{1+\exp\left(-x-\frac{x^3}{12}-\frac{x^5}{80}-\frac{x^7}{448}\right)}=\frac12+\frac x4+O\left(x^9\right)\;.
$$

At this stage, [the plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%20%2F%20%281%20%2B%20exp%20%28-x%20-%20x%5E3%2F12%20-x%5E5%2F80%20-x%5E7%2F448%29%29%20for%20x%3D-4..4) looks very linear indeed – if you go any further, you might as well use a linear function with cut-offs at both ends instead :-)

Comment: Hi joriki,
Thank you very much for your answer. I found that the third function you gave me is very close to what I want. 

Actually, I want to model a response curve of image sensor to brightness of the scene. This curve is quite similar to the one I plotted using my previous sigmoid function. 

This curve passes two point (-1.5,20) and (1.5,80) because I assume that for the pixel value from 20 to 80, an increment of brightness would increase the pixel value to 20.

Comment: My previous curve is not correct in 3 points:
(1) the center is not linear
(2) the varying of brightness is not that long, It should be -4 to 4, not -6 to 6. So the curve should converge to the limit more rapidly and I could get rid the part beyond [-4,4]..
(3) the slope of the curve before the 20 and after 80 should be a little bit higher. (so the curve should converge more rapidly)

Comment: @JamesDo: You're welcome. Since you said that the third function was more useful, I also added the corresponding function with an $x^5$ term to the answer. On your second comment: great coincidence, then, that problems (2) and (3) happened to be addressed by the solution to problem (1) :-)

Comment: From your third function I found that this function is close to what I need
y=1/(1+exp(-ln(4)/1.5*x-x^7/7000)). For the linear part, I use the linear function y=20x+50. The plot of the new curve is shown here

http://i827.photobucket.com/albums/zz197/koifish1987/curve1_zpsmnaozc5d.jpg

The curve does not meet the linear section at two point (-1.5,20) and (1.5,80). But this is enough for me ^.^

Comment: @JamesDo: I see. (Note that there's an $x$ missing in the equation in the image.)

Comment: You're right. x is missing in my figure. I choose the coefficient of -ln4/1.5 for x since I want the curve almost pass two points (-1.5,20) and (1.5,80). The higher order of the additional term makes the curve converge more rapidly (so x^7 instead of x^3). And I found that I need to high denominator for x^7 so that the curve get closer to those two points. Also a high denominator seems to eliminate the wavy things at two ends of the curve. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: @JamesDo: If you wanted the $x^7$ for fast convergence, I'd suggest to include all the terms up to $x^7$ to make the curve as linear as possible. I've added the corresponding function at the end of the answer. Note that it has a much larger $x^7$ term, so it's both "more linear" and converges faster.

Comment: As you suggest in the answer, I think I just need to splice a linear function into a sigmoid. Your final function make the center part is very close to linear. But the center part does not match the linear section (the red line in the image below). 

http://i827.photobucket.com/albums/zz197/koifish1987/curve2_zpswesbdkhn.jpg

I wonder if your function can be change somehow to match the linear section, especially at the two end of the linear section (red line).